# Conditionally commit transactions on MySQL without stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I found [their document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/flow-control-constructs.html) said that the IF ELSE END IF is only supported in stored procedure.

```
MySQL supports the IF, CASE, ITERATE, LEAVE LOOP, WHILE, and REPEAT constructs for flow control within **stored programs**.
```

We tried and seem that it is not supported in running batch statements via cli.

To optimize the performance and reduce round trip, reading the ROW_COUNT() by an application is not considered. The best if mysql can take it in the speed of light.

How do I make it work without using any additional stored procedure?  We tried to use WHERE ROW_COUNT() on every UPDATE to suspend the chain of updates if any one goes wrong; but it wont stop the transaction begin replicated even if nothing should be modified.

EDIT:

In short, how do I do

```
START TRANSACTION
UPDATE `table_a` SET a=1 WHERE id=1 AND addition=2;
UPDATE `table_b` SET a=1 WHERE id=1 AND another_rule=3;
IF UPDATE_COUNT() = 1 
THEN 
  COMMIT
ELSE
  ROLLBACK
END IF
```

In a crond schedule, without using stored procedure.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not clear at all, please rephrase/elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a work around if you don't want to use a stored procedure. it works fine for me

`SET autocommit=0;`
`UPDATE table_a SET a=1 WHERE id=1 AND addition=2;`
`UPDATE table_b SET a=1 WHERE id=1 AND another_rule=3;`
`SET autocommit=IF(UPDATE_COUNT()=1,1,2);`

autocommit will set to be `2` if not `UPDATE_COUNT() = 1` and this will throw an exception
`Variable 'autocommit' can't be set to the value of '2'`
handle this exception and execute `ROLLBACK;`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you want to do is possible, as is, without a stored procedure.  Why are you averse to using a stored procedure?  The only other way I can think of doing this atm, is to have a staging table that can trim your duplicates and then do your commit in one step.

Malks.